# How can I create a custom validation rule and define it in Service Provider a form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm making a form generator on a project, and we've decided to automatically upload files before the user submit their answers. The problem is then that we can't use a premade rule for the validation to check if the media as been uploaded if it's required, because the field will be empty at the submit. Plus, we also require a media if a radio button as a defined value (for example : do you need to rent a car? Yes/No; if yes, please upload a scan of your driving license).

I've read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)  about custom validation rules, but the forms and ruleset are defined in a json stored in the db, so I can't call the rule like `new CustomValidationRule`. I wanted to create a shortcut to make it look like a "real" rule and that could be stored in my json with no problem.

Here is a code that is working to make my custom rule to do what I want.

##### `AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Boot the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('media_required_if', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            if ($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]] == $parameters[1]) {

                $model = request()->route($parameters[2]);
                $media = $model->getMedia('attachments', ['input_name' => $attribute]);

                if (count($media) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }, "The dropzone :attribute must contain at least a file.");
```

It is invoked like this in the ruleset `media_required_if:rent_car,1,model`. It's a rule can exclusively for an update, so I can have the model, check if media has been uploaded yet for this attribute (there can be more dropzones, all depending of other rules), and check if there is at least one file store. I need these 3 parameters.

But I don't think `AppServiceProvider` is the best place to store this rule, and I'd like to only keep the invokation here and the declaration with its snake case name.

Here's what I tried and is not working:

```php
   Validator::extend('media_required_if', new MediaRequiredIf, "The dropzone :attribute must contain at least a file.");
```

```php
namespace App\Rules;

/// uses

class MediaRequiredIf implements DataAwareRule, InvokableRule, ValidatorAwareRule
{
    protected $data = [];
    protected $validator = [];
    
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail)
    {
        dd($this->data, $this->validator);
        // Here I want to put the code that works, but $this->data and $this->value aren't filled.
        
    }

    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setValidator($validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I don't understand but `$this->data` and `$this->validator` always return `[]`, whatever I do.
I tried to follow the documentation but it's not really clear, and I also tried to follow older documentations (from 8.* to 5.2), but the code is really different and I don't want to make code that will be obsolete in a week. Is it even possible to do that?
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

- You can use `required_if` to check the driving licence.
- Add a hidden input and check it after the file is uploaded. Then use `exclude_if`, so it will be excluded from validation.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?